# ORACLE APEX Sentencia IF con operador OR para mostrar un mensaje

Tags: oracle, apex

Amigos, pasa que tengo la siguiente duda de como hacer para que funcione los siguientes casos de uso.

- Mostrar error "Cuando un elemento no tiene un tipo de formato A1B2C3.1".
- Mostrar error "Cuando un elemento no tiene un tipo de formato 1A2B3C.D1".
- Mostrar error "Cuando no tiene ninguno de los 2 formatos".

Se trata de que en el sistema entra una numeración (en una textfield) y es evaluado a travez de un paquete de `Oracle` el cual resuelve el tipo de formato para ese número, asi como en el sistema donde esta corriendo. Tengo lo siguiente.

```
        IF v_fuente ='Sistema_1' THEN
      IF REGEXP_SUBSTR(:P4000_IDLOT, PKG_Sistemas.SistemaUnoFormatRegexp) IS NULL THEN
        RETURN 'El lote no tiene un formato valido para Sistema 1';
      END IF;
    ELSE
        IF REGEXP_SUBSTR(:P4000_IDLOT, PKG_Sistemas.SistemaDosFormatRegexp) IS NULL THEN
            RETURN 'El lote no tiene un formato valido de Sistema 2';
      END IF;
    END IF;
```

El `REGEXP_SUBSTR` tengo entendido que es una función de Oracle para formatear un texto.

`P4000_IDLOT` Es una caja de texto donde se introduce el número a evaluar.

Sucede que necesito cumplir los 3 casos de uso mencionados anteriormente.

Me aconsejaron usar `OR` en la logica de decisión, solo que no soy muy diestro para APEX. Algun consejo?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto y adaptalo a tu necesidad:

```
declare 
 v_valor   varchar2(40) := 'A1B2C3.1';
 v_fuente   varchar2(40) := 'Sistema_1';
begin
    if  REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_valor, '^\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z][.][A-Z]\d{1}') IS NULL and REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_valor, '^[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[.]\d{1}') IS NULL then
       RETURN 'No tiene ninguno de los dos formatos'; 
    elsif v_fuente ='Sistema_1' and REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_valor, '^[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[.]\d{1}') IS NULL THEN
       RETURN 'El lote no tiene un formato valido para Sistema 1';
    elsif v_fuente = 'Sistema_2' and REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_valor, '^\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z][.][A-Z]\d{1}') IS NULL then
       RETURN 'El lote no tiene un formato valido para Sistema 2';
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Tus contribuciones serán mejor recibidas si explicas cómo tu publicación puede ayudar a solucionar el problema, pues las respuestas que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad.

Comment: Probaré la forma que mencionas @MiltonAragon